# How to display the latest date at present?

Tags: javascript, node.js

It is necessary to display from the array only that date which will be the largest in comparison with the current date. As a result, I have all the dates displayed.

```
const states = States.select().exec()

var curr = new Date();

for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
  var maxDate = Math.max(new Date(states[i]._props.state_date))
  if (curr > maxDate) {
    console.log(states[i]._props.state_date)
  }
}
```

Example states:

```
_props:{ 
   state_id: 12,
   state_date: 2019-08-15T07:00:00.000Z,
   users_id: 1,
   comments: null 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
const states = States.select().exec()

var largest = null

for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
  var currDate = new Date(states[i]._props.state_date))
  if (!largest || currDate > largest) {
    largest = currDate
  }
} 
console.log(largest)
```